# Will VS2010 work with Visual Source Safe 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Until I can convince others to convert over to Team Foundation Server 2010 (TFS2010), I'm still going to use Visual Source Safe 2005 (VSS2005). I will be upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010) soon.  What do I need to get VS2010 to work with VSS2005?  I understand there is a patch for VSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's [the patch](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a1a68d8-db11-417c-91ad-02aab484776b&displaylang=en). I'm not sure if this is all you need to make this work or not.

Answer (score 4):

If the VSS client is installed on your dev box, the VSS plugin will appear in the source control plugin selection list in tools|options|source control inside of Visual Studio.

VSS is terrible. Really, really bad. I mean, you might think that the asteroid that killed the aliens that lived here before the dinosaurs was bad, but that's just peanuts compared to VSS.

However, if you're stuck with it, it will, in fact, work with VS2010. I'm in a quandary because I want to move to TFS, but the content managers are using SharePoint Designer (effectively Expression, since we don't have a SharePoint site). They're used to saving the file and immediately seeing their changes on the dev server. Other than installing Visual Studio on their machines, there doesn't seem to be a good way to let them keep this functionality while moving to a real source control system.

I feel your pain.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion.. Ditch VSS and use [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/), it's free, it's got VS2010 integration tools, and it's better than VSS (again, my opinion). I'd get into why but there are [plenty of rants about that](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/04/choosing-source-control-tool.html).

If you like Visual Studio integration, [Ankh SVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) works great. Also, we use [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for quick access from Windows Explorer.

All of that said, if our team was a little larger, I think TFS would be totally worth it.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) is also a very popular choice, but the way it manages things might make it a bit slow for extremely large solutions. (I've only read evidence to that fact, I've not tried it myself)

Comment: I would say if he's having trouble convincing people to move off VSS, he'd have his work cut out trying to get them to switch to Git (or any DVCS, really)! But I certainly agree that would be the ideal... I've never tried TFS myself, but my understanding that it's more of a product life cycle management tool (bug database, project management, source control, etc all-in-one) so something like SVN may actually be *less* of a jump than TFS.

Comment: +1 codeka... it's certainly a hard sell, that's to be sure, but that lack of VSS support OOTB in VS2010 makes that sell a little easier, especially with that hefty price tag on TFS.

Comment: I’m a one man developer here.  Six years ago, I had a hard time convincing the IT guy and boss to setup VSS.  The boss just started using it a year ago.  "TFS Basic" looks like the next step to take.  I have played with Ankh SVN at home.  Little steps at a time, I get things upgraded and still keep the business going.

Comment: @blesh this doesn't really seem to answer the question. The problem isn't that VSS sucks, but that he is stuck with it.

Comment: @David Lively  we had this same question, and the answer was to switch to SVN. ;)

Comment: @blesh Typically When someone asks "How to I get from A to B?", it's because they're already at A. Telling them to start at C, and that being at A is a bad idea, will not help them reach their destination.

Comment: I agree - this doesn't answer the question. Some people are just stuck with VSS.

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 supports VSS out of box. Go to Tools > Option > Source control change it from TFS to VSS